# PCLVisualizer within a ROS node does not respond

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I want to visualize my pointcloud data and some objects within a ROS node. The node receives the data via a ROS Topic. The problem I have is how to integrate the viewer properly. In the main class I am using a member variable for the viewer and one thread which should update the view.

```
boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> visualizer_thread_;
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer_;
```

In the constructor of my class (basically a segmentation class) I initialize the viewer and start the thread to do the update.

```
 viewer_= boost::make_shared<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer>("Cylinder Viewer");
 visualizer_thread_.reset(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&CylinderSegmentation::visualize,this)));
```

In the visualization thread I do basically an spin operation on the view

```
/** Visualizer Thread for the objects
*
*/
void visualize(){
   ros::Rate r(40);
   viewer_->setBackgroundColor(10.5,0.5,1.0);
   viewer_->addCoordinateSystem(1.0);     
   while (!viewer_->wasStopped()){
      viewer_->spinOnce();
      r.sleep();
   }     
   std::cout<<"Stopped the Viewer"<<std::endl;
 }
```

When I close the viewer window, I receive the message "Stopped the Viewer" but the window does not close. I cannot even add something to the window to be shown. Is there something wrong I do about the usage of the PCLViewer?

Cheers,

Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47097/pclvisualizer-within-a-ros-node-does-not-respond/) by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-10-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Markus,

I had the same problem. I solved it by creating the visualizer in my thread function, e.g. your visualize(). Would be interesting to know the reason of this problem.

Cheers,
Christian

---

Originally posted by [christiank](https://answers.ros.org/users/1553/christiank/) with karma: 113 on 2012-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on 2016-06-30**:
Could you post an example? I'm dealing with the same issue. Thanks!

**Comment by [jtim](https://answers.ros.org/users/27497/jtim/) on 2017-01-23**:
@vkee did you get it working?

**Comment by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on 2017-01-23**:
@jtim Yes I did. I modified https://github.com/dirkholz/pcl_online_viewer.

**Comment by [jtim](https://answers.ros.org/users/27497/jtim/) on 2017-01-23**:
Thanks found another way quite simple http://stackoverflow.com/a/41814275/2076775